# Is there any minimum votes needed to trigger the serial downvoting logic?

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

I become a victim of serial down-voting. But Stackoverflow's script didn't return it back. I lost 10 reputations. I had flagged twice and the moderator accept it as helpful, but no luck.

[image]

I know the details of the algorithm aren't public, but I just want to make sure this.

I don't care about 10 reputations, but 5 downvotes will not be count as serial down-voting??

Comment: We don't know.  The details of the algorithm are not made public, as you already pointed out.

Comment: @Libin - Are you sure you want to go public with this? Now we know that 5 revenge downvotes is working. *Not* good to know.

Comment: @BoPersson I know the risk. But just wants to make sure what happens to the algorithm. Thats why I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a voting pattern like that has 99% odds of being a single user serially downvoting you.  There have been plenty of posts at meta that noted that less than 6 down-votes doesn't trigger the automatic reversal script.

I'm not an [html] expert, but I upvoted the most inappropriatly down-voted posts, easily canceling the loss of rep.

Comment: Thank you so much @uphill. Thats a great support for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends from the number of users who down-voted you. If those votes are casted from the same user, then it's serial down-voting. If there are four users who down-voted you, then it's not serial down-voting.

Moderators depend much from the tools Stack Exchange offer them, to detect serial down-voting. If the automatic script didn't detect that, moderators can do few.

Comment: Thank you. But in my case the moderator didn't gave me any reply like that. Just I saw was, my flag was helpful. Also you can see the time. It happens in just 2mins. So I believe its from a single user. Right?

Comment: Moderators cannot reply, when handling flags. They can just mark a flag as helpful, or decline it; when they decline it, they select a reason for declining it. Flags are generally not a two-way communication channel with moderators. As for being a single user to down-vote, that is not said; three different users could have down-voted your questions. If it were a single user, the down-voted would be reversed the day after they were casted.

Comment: Well said. Thank you. :)